# WCF username / password validation not working

Tags: wcf, basichttpbinding

I've implemented username / password authentication with basicHttpBinding in code. Problem is, that no validation is required when calling from client. I can call all methods, like no validation was being set on the server side. I've expected that username and password should be provided from client side, otherwise this will not work. But, it's not like that.

On the client side, I've simply added reference to the web service and started call methods.

Any idea why is that?

Server code:

```
String adress1 = "http://localhost/CalculatorService";
        Uri[] baseAddresses = { new Uri(adress1) };

        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService), baseAddresses);

        ServiceCredentials cd = new ServiceCredentials();
        cd.UserNameAuthentication.UserNamePasswordValidationMode = UserNamePasswordValidationMode.Custom;
        cd.UserNameAuthentication.CustomUserNamePasswordValidator = new CustomUserNameValidator();

        BasicHttpBinding b1 = new BasicHttpBinding();
        b1.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
        b1.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;

        ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;

        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(cd);
        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

        EndpointAddress adr1 = new EndpointAddress(baseAddresses[0]);

        ServiceEndpoint en1 = new ServiceEndpoint(ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(ICalculator)));
        en1.Binding = b1;
        en1.Address = adr1;

        host.Open();
```

Class for username / password validation:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class CustomUserNameValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
  {
    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
      if(userName.ToLower() != "test" || password.ToLower() != "test1")
      {
        throw new SecurityTokenException("Unknown Username or Incorrect Password");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Interface:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  [ServiceContract]
  public interface ICalculator
  {
    [OperationContract]
    double Add(double n1, double n2);
    [OperationContract]
    double Subtract(double n1, double n2);
    [OperationContract]
    double Multiply(double n1, double n2);
    [OperationContract]
    double Divide(double n1, double n2);
  }
}
```

Class:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  public class CalculatorService : ICalculator
  {
    public double Add(double n1, double n2)
    {
      return n1 + n2;
    }
    public double Subtract(double n1, double n2)
    {
      return n1 - n2;
    }
    public double Multiply(double n1, double n2)
    {
      return n1 * n2;
    }
    public double Divide(double n1, double n2)
    {
      return n1 / n2;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that I forgot was to add endpoint to the host.

```
host.AddServiceEndpoint(en1);
```

And on the client side, binding should be:

```
<bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICalculator">
            <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
              <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
            </security>
          </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

And then, call:

```
WCFUserPass.CalculatorClient client = new WCFUserPass.CalculatorClient();     
  client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "test";
  client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "test";
  var result = client.Add(1, 3);
```